# PyBrain cannot access function listed in API/Index

Tags: python, pybrain

So, I'll make it simple.

Pybrain's API shows that they have, as an example, a function called `buildNetwork()`. It says it's in the `pybrain.tools.shortcut.buildNetwork`, if that makes sense?

The problem is, `.shortcut` doesn't exist. I'm very new to using APIs but it appears to me that this function doesn't even exist.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

```
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
....
buildNetwork(....)
```

should do it.

Comment: I got it. I thought just saying "import pybrain" would automatically import *everything*....

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Apparently I have to *specify*, for one reason or another, that I want to import pybrain.tools.shortcuts, I can't just mass import pybrain and expect shortcuts to show up. Thanks for reading this......I guess